# Stuck on (a) Bridge! ;-)

Tags: modeling

I'm not-quite-a newbie, learning modeling in Blender. I think I'm following the appropriate steps.
Created Two Cubes
Subdivided both cubes twice
Selected four faces on Cube1
Selected (opposing) four faces on Cube2
Right click, choose "Bridge"

I receive the following error: "Select at least two edge loops"

I can't seem to connect two (or more) faces no matter what I try. What might I be doing wrong?

TIA!
[image]
(v2.93.5 Mac)

Comment: are these cubes 2 separate objects?

Comment: Yes, it is obvious, posting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is, that the cubes are separate objects. Separate objects **cannot share vertices**, but bridging the faces would create exactly that.

Merge cubes into one object using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in Object mode, works just fine.

Comment: THAT'S IT!!! TYSM!!! I'm bock on the road!!! So... I visually see that Blender colored each cube differently (one was orange, the other deep red), but when I pressed Ctrl+J, they became orange.

GREAT great GREAT!!! Thanks for the assist!!